# Using the + operator in boost::spirit: char cast error?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

In boost::spirit, I am trying to use the `+(...)` syntax to match one or more strings, like here:

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace client
{
  namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
  namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

  template <typename Iterator>
  bool parse(Iterator first, Iterator last)
  {
    using qi::char_;

    qi::rule< Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type > text;
    qi::rule< Iterator, std::string() > myword;

    text = '"' >> +( myword ) >> '"'; // ERROR!
    myword = +char_;  

    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first, last, text, ascii::space);
    if (first != last)
      return false;
    return r;
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
foo.cpp:20:   instantiated from 'bool client::parse
boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:109: error: \
  invalid static_cast from type \
  'const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' \
  to type 'char'
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `lit` or `char_` to wrap those literals?

Comment: Ugh, IMO this is such an ugly use of operator overloading.

Comment: @nightcracker Boost.Spirit is nevertheless probably the best parser generator there is. Certainly of those that are in-language.

Comment: I do like it, too. But it seems there is a steep learning curve, to get subtle things right and compilable; my operator usage looks to me just like they did it with `*node` here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html

Comment: @Frank : I don't have time to post a full answer at the moment, but the issue is that the attribute type of `+myword` is `vector<string>`, not `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles just fine with Boost V1.47 (Spirit V2.5). In this version of Spirit the attribute handling has been completely rewritten which fixes this issue (and a lot of other issues).